# .NET 5 Blazor WASM StringFormat Currency

Tags: c#, string-formatting, currency, blazor-webassembly

I display some currencies in UK culture :

```
value.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
```

But since I have switched my code to .NET 5, I have the following result :

**GBP124.00**

How can i get back **£124.00** by still using **C0** or **C2** ?

### EDIT : Complementary infos according to responses

I'm working in Blazor WebAssembly.
Here an exemple :

(fiddle: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/2dyefc8o)

```
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization

@FormatDefaultFloatCurrency(price)
<br />
@FormatFloatCurrency(price)
<br />
@FormatFloatCurrencyISO(price)

@code {

    float price = 4897;

    string FormatDefaultFloatCurrency(float value)
    {
        var regionCode = "en-GB";
        return value.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(regionCode));
    }

    string FormatFloatCurrency(float value)
    {
        var regionCode = "en-GB";
        var region = new RegionInfo(regionCode);
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(regionCode);
        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = region.CurrencySymbol;

        return value.ToString("C0", culture);
    }

    string FormatFloatCurrencyISO(float value)
    {
        var regionCode = "en-GB";
        var region = new RegionInfo(regionCode);
        var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(regionCode);
        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = region.ISOCurrencySymbol;

        return value.ToString("C0", culture);
    }
}
```

In .NET Core 3.1 (the version blazorFiddle uses) :

```
£4,897
£4,897
GBP4,897
```

And the results I get in .NET 5 :

```
GBP4,897
GBP4,897
GBP4,897
```

Comment: Do you have a repro for this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/kn76GQ returns `£124.00` using that code in .Net 5

Comment: I too cannot reproduce this on a fully up-to-date-at-this-time Windows 10 using .NET 5, even if I set `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");` first. Have you checked the regional settings on the PC that's producing the problem?

Comment: I've edited the question, I'm using Blazor WASM

Comment: `return $"£{value:N2}";`? N.B. You really should use the `decimal` type for currency, not `float`.

Comment: Yeah I still can make my own format. It is just weird I have not the same result in .NET 5. Thanks for the advice, I will take it into account.

Comment: It looks like it happens for several cultures: you could add your voice to [Blazor WASM format as currency shows "AUD" instead of "$"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45262) if you want to.

Comment: Yeah it's look like the same error. I could fix it by adding <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData> in the project file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45262, it seems there is an issue with the cultures in Blazor webAssembly.

You can add

```
<BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
```

in the client project file (.csproj), inside *PropertyGroup*

Comment: This worked for me, .NET 6.

Answer (score 1):

Despite I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, I think I might be able to help you.

You can use the following snippet to set the currency symbol:

```cs
var regionCode= "en-GB";
var region = new RegionInfo(regionCode);
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(regionCode);

culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = region.CurrencySymbol;

var currencyString = value.ToString("C2", culture);
```

Also, if you ever needed to explicitly set the currency symbol to the three-character-code you may simply change the line

```cs
// that results in "£124.00"
 culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = region.CurrencySymbol;
```

to one

```cs
// that results in "GBP124.00" 
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = region.ISOCurrencySymbol;
```

Comment: That still doesn't work if the currency symbol has been set to "GBP" in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for this detailled answear, but I did not mention I was on Blazor. I thought there was no differences with a .NET 5 project

Answer (score 0):

Both C0 and C2 return £124.00 for me in .NET 5

Please check your system currency format in Region Settings

Control Panel > Region (choose United Kingdom)> Formats  > Advanced (or Additionals Setting) > Currency

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPapN.png)

Comment: Thanks, but here I want to specify the UK culture for everyone, no matter there local culture.

Comment: Yes, i think u can try to set in your web server